# Posterior probabilities of variables that aren't included in likelihood

Tags: bayesian, estimation

*Disclaimer*: I'm not a statistician so I apologize if this is a trivial question or written in a way that convolutes ideas and abuses jargon.  It seems like a problem that should be common but I haven't had any luck finding the answer, maybe because I just didn't know the right words...

I have a very complicated model (to be precise, models of stars) that takes a number of parameters (e.g. the mass of the star), currently 3, which I'll denote $t$, $M$ and $Z$, and returns a number of observable features (e.g. brightness, colour), which I'll call $\vec{x}_m$. My current goal is to compute the distributions of the parameters ($t$, $M$, $Z$) that correspond to a subset of observations $\vec{x}_o$, which are presumed to be independently Gaussian-distributed.  Note that I'm not fitting *all* the observables $\vec{x}_o$, only some subset of them.  There are up to about 8 in total but I usually only match 2 or 3, sometimes 6. That means there are usually a few "observables" (i.e. additional outputs for each model) that aren't used to constrain the parameters.

What I want to know is, how do I calculate the posterior probabilities of these "unused" observables?

For the parameters, I understand I should marginalize by integrating over the others (right?). So, if the parameters are $t$, $M$ and $Z$, I would get the posterior distribution of $t$ by integrating $M$ and $Z$ over their domains. i.e.

$$P(t|\vec x_o)=\iint P(t,M,Z|\vec x_o)dMdZ$$

But what about the unused observables?

My wild guess would be that I could introduce the observable, say, $u(t,M,Z)$ (which wasn't in the likelihood function) as if it were an extra parameter, then marginalize over the original three. Something like letting $P(u,t,M,Z|\vec x_o)=P(t,M,Z|\vec x_o)$ and computing

$$P(u|\vec x_o)=\iiint P(u,t,M,Z|\vec x_o)dtdMdZ$$

As a secondary point, if I look for this kind of posterior distribution, should I recover my original constraints if I apply my method to the variables in the likelihood? In other words, if I match models using e.g. brightness, and I then find the posterior distribution of the brightness by whatever method we devise here, should it match the relevant data point i.e. the relevant Gaussian?

Let me know if this question makes sense.  I appreciate that it probably doesn't!

Comment: You seem to change notation (from theta/x to specific featuers) in the middle of the question; this makes it harder to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If indeed $u$ is the part of the data you chose not to use and hence treat as unobserved, the correct quantity is the predictive distribution on $u$ given $x_0$, which usually writes as
   $$
   \int p(u|t,M,Z) p(t,M,Z|x_0) \, \text{d}t\text{d}M\text{d}Z
   $$
   if $u$ and $x_0$ are independent.
2. I am afraid I do not understand your second point. I do not see how you get a posterior conditional on the brightness ($x_0$?) and then compute the posterior of the brightness...

Comment: Thanks, it seems the term *posterior predictive distribution* was the keyword I was missing all along.  What do I do with *P(u|t,M,Z)* if I only have *u* as a function of *t*, *M* and *Z*? Should I use *P(u|t,M,Z)=δ(u-u(t,M,Z))*?

Comment: In the event $u$ is a _deterministic_ function of $(t,M,Z)$, you are simply looking at the _projection_ of the posterior distribution $p(t,M,Z|x_0)$ using the function $u$. (I would not speak of _predictive_ then...)